# Passing parameters from Jenkins to Ansible playbook

Tags: jenkins, ansible

How can I pass parameters from Jenkins to my Ansible playbook? Eg. I want to take IP address from users and pass it to the playbook so that it will execute only on those machines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use -e switch for that purpose:

```
ansible-playbook -e 'foo=${FOO}'
```

where the FOO can be defined in the Jenkins envirionment variables. If it is defined within the parameters block of your Jenkinsfile, then you need to use `${params.foo}`. Then, the value can be accessed by the Ansible playbook with `{{ foo }}`.